# Google Calendar: How can I delete file code that i import to gmail calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I import file  to Google  calendar that create each day other event for few years! I want delete this events.
The problem that events not connect between them, its looks that file generate independent event every day.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to delete multiple events that all have a similar property or keyword.  This is not currently possible with Google Calendar.

You might want to comment on one of these pages and hope that this feature is implemented soon:

- http://getsatisfaction.com/google/topics/mass_delete_for_google_calendar_events
- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=28208b51884b8e23&hl=en

It also looks like the suggest a feature page for Google Calendar was disabled: http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157620